# Both Camino and Firefox on OS X Crash Immediately Upon Startup

Tags: macos, firefox, crash

I was uploading some pictures in Camino to Facebook and it hard crashed.
Camino crashes now upon almost all web pages while trying to load.

Firefox crashes the second it tries to restore its lost session. Not even a chance to stop the webpage.

Safari works fine.

Any ideas what could be going on? xD

Comment: Consider accepting answers to your open questions, or posting answers on your own if you found them in the meantime, as your questions get bumped to the front page otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

In OS X you can start firefox in safe mode by holding down the option key when opening the app.  This way you don't have to start with a fresh profile and can troubleshoot the problem by removing old sessions and disabling addons, etc.  Not sure if camino works the same way, but I'll check it out next time I open up my powerbook and update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how Camino stores its profile, but if you relocate your entire ~/Library/Firefox folder to your desktop and relaunch Firefox, it should create a fresh profile that won't crash.  It's pretty easy to rescue your bookmarks from the folder you moved as well, although it's not a good idea to put anything else into your new profile.